# Building a lib file for c

Tags: c, .lib

I want to build my own library file for c.
How do I do it?
Is there anyway doing it just with a notepad, and then using it some sort of compiler?
I know I can make .lib files with VS, but I want to make it in the most basic way.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

I read this walkthrough but, as I said, I want something more basic.

Basically, I want to make a header file, and just throw it in to the INCLUDE folder wich is in Microsoft_VS_12.0\VC

Comment: You've read that and still want something more basic than `When you build on the Visual Studio command line, you must build the program in two steps. First, run cl /c /EHsc MathFuncsLib.cpp to compile the code and create an object file that's named MathFuncsLib.obj. […] Second, run lib MathFuncsLib.obj to link the code and create the static library MathFuncsLib.lib. […]`?

Comment: YES.. as i said, im looking to do it without the VS

Comment: Uhh... What are you planning on (1) compiling the code; and (2) linking it with?

Comment: Isn't Notepad -> VS Command Prompt -> C compiler (`cl`) -> Library Manager (`lib`) what you're looking for? Without VS you only have Notepad. Do you need help with compiling and linking your code on the command line?